# Price and stock update on company website

Tags: web, self-updating

My company website has a lot of products with different prices and I was wondering if there is any way that I would be able to link my website to multiple supplier websites so that when they delete and upload new products and prices, it will change on my company website automatically.

At the moment I am doing it manually, however, by the time I finish uploading a new lot of products have been uploaded and some old products deleted so I can't keep up.

Hope someone can help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are inserting and updating data in your website back end and then fetching it.
It will be better if you can ask APIs from your supplier websites and directly show data from APIs in your website.
In this case you can get data to your website as in your supplier website.